# How can I add PATH on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to add PATH to packages on `eb deploy`.
Packages are Installed to `/var/www/html/vendor/bin`

It can be add by manually through SSH, but how can I add PATH with config file.

I have config file like this `.ebextensions/ec2.config`. `01-set_timezone` works fine `02-set_path` dosen't

```
commands:
  01-set_timezone:
    command: cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Japan /etc/localtime
  02-set_path:
    command: export PATH=$PATH:/var/www/html/vendor/bin
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

each command is performed in its own shell. so the export won't work. you'd need to put it into `~/.bash_profile` to ensure it's executed with every new command.

```
commands:
  set_path:
    test: test ! -f /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.post-provisioning-complete
    command: echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/var/www/html/vendor/bin' >> /root/.bash_profile
```

to make it run only once, add the following file:

.ebextensions/99_finalize_setup.config:

```
commands:
  99_write_post_provisioning_complete_file:
    command: touch /opt/elasticbeanstalk/.post-provisioning-complete
```

Comment: This will be added PATH to `.bash_profile` every deploy. Is there any way to add path once on each instance.

Comment: This is the key part of the answer: `each command is performed in its own shell` -- understanding that allowed us to make progress in referencing custom installs of Anaconda & Python and ensuring we were using the right installs of Conda & Flask in subsequent commands in our config script.

Answer (score 0):

To have the PATH available during setup you can do the following.

Create a config file `.ebextensions/set_path.conf`

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    "PATH": "/var/www/html/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```